# MySQL. search data in serialized column

Tags: mysql

I have table workers and table worksheets.

This two tables are linked by column "worker_id"

In worksheets we have some data about workers as birthday, sex and other.
This data is saved in one column as serialized array

something like:

`{"photo":"image.png","sex":"male","birthday":"14.09.2018","phone":"8(777)777-7778"}`

My task is to get workers over 20 years old and under 30 years old for example

How can I do it?
Also in birthday key may be null values

I will be glad of any help

Comment: Maybe take a look at the built-in JSON functions

Answer (score 2):

You can use `json_extract` to get data from `json` in MySQL

```
set @json = '{"age": 25,"photo":"image.png","sex":"male","birthday":"14.09.2018","phone":"8(777)777-7778"}';
select json_extract(@json, '$.sex'); //returns "male"
```

I suppose you are looking to a query like this:

```
select *
  from workers w
 inner join worksheets ws on w.id = ws.worker_id
 where json_extract(ws.json_field, '$.age') > 20
```

Take a look at `MySQL` `JSON` functions
[MYSQL Json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)

Comment: seems that my mysql server is old for "json_extract", because I got error "json_extract is not exist". May be there any other soultions?

Comment: @Baurzhan which version of mysql server are you using?

Comment: version is 5.0.12

Comment: MySQL native JSON functions was implemented on version 5.7.8 as the docs says, I think in your case you'll could try to implement your own function or update it to a new version

Comment: @Baurzhan can't you update your MySQL version?

Comment: I can't update MySQL version because this is not my database